# CSS class working with textarea but not with input text

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a CSS class defined as follow:

```
.form_bg_color{ background: red; }
```

And in my view, i have the following form line:

```
<%= f.text_field :source, class: "form_bg_color" %>
```

This should change the color of the input box, but it does not work.

So I made some tests. I changed the form line to:

```
<%= f.text_field :source, style: "background:red;" %>
```

This works. Also, using text_area instead and the class also works:

```
<%= f.text_area :source, class: "form_bg_color" %>
```

Could someone tell me why text_field doesn't accept my class?

Comment: Unless the problem is related to the template code itself, only provide the generated HTML.

Comment: I would post, but the html is fine. It is generating the divs and classes properly. Like Mark said bellow, I guess it is something with the specificity.

Comment: You're supposed to be providing enough code to replicate the problem, otherwise it is difficult to debug.  Template code and one line of CSS doesn't do that.

Comment: I have no CSS customizing forms in rails. If I had, I would have posted the html generated or my CSS. The only CSS I have is that form_bg_color. If you have programmed in rails (even for little time like me) then you know what the html will look like. And like I said, the html is fine. I debugged it on the browser. The problem is that I wasn't aware of how CSS calculated precedence of conflicting attributes, not the generated html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have a CSS specificity conflict that is preventing your class `.form_bg_color` from taking effect.

If the class by itself, for example:

```
<%= f.text_field :source, class: "form_bg_color" %>
```

does not work, but the inline style works:

```
<%= f.text_field :source, style: "background:red;" %>
```

then there is another CSS rule of higher specificity taking effect.

You might need to try something like:

```
input.form_bg_color {}
```

but you need to look at other styles that select the `input` fields.

The fact that the class works on a `textarea` may or may not be relevant.

For more information about the specificity of CSS selectors,
see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity